# Getting error while moving expandable table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am getting error while moving expandable table view up and down. 
This is my error
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

```
arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"obj1",@"obj2",@"obj3",@"obj4",nil];
arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Name1", @"name2", @"name3", @"name4", @"name5", @"name6", nil];
arr2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"arr2obj", nil];
arr3 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"arr3obj", nil];
arr4 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"arr4obj", nil];
```

This is my code...

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([arrSelectedSectionIndex containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]])
    {
        if (section == 0) {
            return arr1.count;
        } else if (section == 1) {
            return arr2.count ;
        } else if (section == 2) {
            return arr3.count;
        }else if (section == 3) {
            return arr4.count;
        }
    } else {

        return 0;
    }

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewControllerCell *cell; // = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCell"];


    cell= (ViewControllerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.faqLbl.text = [tempArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    ViewControllerCellHeader *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCellHeader"];

    headerView.faqLblTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    headerView.faqLblTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    headerView.faqLblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.0];

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
    {
        headerView.faqLblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25.0];

    }

    if (headerView ==nil)
    {
        [tblView registerClass:[ViewControllerCellHeader class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCellHeader"];

        headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCellHeader"];
    }

    headerView.faqLblTitle.text = [arr objectAtIndex:section];

    if ([arrSelectedSectionIndex containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]])
    {
        headerView.faqBtnShowHide.selected = YES;
    }

    [[headerView faqBtnShowHide] setTag:section];
    headerView.faqBtnShowHide.tag = section;

    [[headerView faqBtnShowHide] addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapShowHideSection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return headerView.contentView;
}

-(IBAction)btnTapShowHideSection:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (!sender.selected)
    {
        [arrSelectedSectionIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];

        sender.selected = YES;
    }else{
        sender.selected = NO;

        if ([arrSelectedSectionIndex containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]])
        {
            [arrSelectedSectionIndex removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sender.tag]];
        }
    }

    [tblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sender.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    - (IBAction)dropDownButton:(UIButton *)sender {

        if(sender.tag == 0) {
            tempArr = arr1;
        } else if (sender.tag == 1) {
            tempArr = arr2;
        } else if (sender.tag == 2) {
            tempArr = arr3;
        } else if (sender.tag == 3) {
            tempArr = arr4;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the use of - (IBAction)dropDownButton:(UIButton *)sender  method?

Comment: it's assign array to dynamically for cells....

Comment: When it will be called?

Comment: I have drop down button on cel, when I click it will called....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        tempArr = arr1;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        tempArr = arr2;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        tempArr = arr3;
    } else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        tempArr = arr4;
    }

    ViewControllerCell *cell; // = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCell"];


    cell= (ViewControllerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.faqLbl.text = [tempArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
```

You were calling reload section without initializing `tempArr` `numberOfRowsInSection` is considering the actual data sources like arr1,arr2 etc but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is depending on `tempArr` to populate cell. Obviously if tempArr's value is not same as the actual data source which returned the number of cells it will break.

Comment: @ios-developer : Sorry my mistake lemme update the answer